# debundle single browser js code into original files

Tags: javascript, requirejs, webpack, amd, commonjs

I have a js file with following structure:

```
define("example/example", ["exports", "example/something", "example/other", "ex/sthg"], function(e, t, n, a, r) {
    e["default"] = {something: 'example'}

}), define("examle/module", ["exports"], function(e) {
    ///
}), define("examle/module2", ["exports"], function(e) {
    // and so on...
}), require("example/sthg")["default"].callSomething({
    //
});
```

I'm looking for a way to unpack this file into original files, like `example/example.js`, `example/module`, `example/module2` etc.

I've tried `browser-unpack`, but with no effect so I assume that isn't bundled with `browserify`. Syntax looks similar to `AMD` or `RequireJS`.

Is there any away to debundle file like that?

Comment: I doubt it. How would any unbundle script know where one file ends and another starts?

Answer (score 0):

Quick monkey solution, which helps me enough - it creates modules tree with import list and `function(e, t, n...` as a file content. Maybe it can be useful for someone. In my case, it can be fully debundled (of course only to js, not jsx), but I don't want to play with js parsers.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');

const defineArgs = ['e', 't', 'n', 'a', 'r']
function parseFunction(func, deps) {
    let funcStr = func.toString(),
        depsArr = [],
        depsStr = ''

    // just to know what etnar is
    for(let i in deps) {
        if(deps[i]!='exports') {
            depsArr.push('const ' + defineArgs[i] + ' = require("' + deps[i] + '")')
        }
    }

    depsStr = depsArr.join('\n')

    return depsStr + '\n' + funcStr
}
// override define
var define = function(filename, deps, func) {
    console.log(filename + ': ' + deps)
    let outPath = 'src/' + filename + '.js',
        outDir = path.dirname(outPath),
        out = parseFunction(func, deps)

    try {
        fs.lstatSync(outDir)
    } catch (e) {
        mkdirp(outDir, function(err) { if(err){console.error(err)} })
    }

    fs.writeFile(outPath, out, function(err) {
        if(err){console.error(err)}
    })
}
// paste your script below and run this via node
// define("example/example", ["exports", "example/something", .......
```